# Gulp File Not Recoginizing Changes to js files

Tags: angular, visual-studio, gulp

I'm relatively new to gulp and am working with a wrapbootstrap template that employs it.

It doesn't seem to be picking up on changes to our js files when creating the output js file.

The files that aren't being picked up on are angularjs files locted in wwwroot > components > App_Scripts > Controllers/Services/Directives

Here is a look at my gulpfile. I'm trying to use console.log() to view where things are going wrong, but don't actually see the events being logged in the console in chrome.

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    less = require("gulp-less"),
    rtlcss = require("gulp-rtlcss");

var paths = { webroot: "./wwwroot/" };
paths.components = paths.webroot + 'components/';
paths.appScripts = paths.webroot + 'components/App_Scripts';
paths.controllers = paths.appScripts + "/Controllers";
paths.services = paths.appScripts + "/Services";
paths.modals = paths.appScripts + "/Modals";

// Sources
paths.js = [
    paths.components + 'app.js',
    paths.components + '**/*.js',
    paths.appScripts + "corePowerApp.js",
    paths.controllers + '**/*.js',
    paths.services + '**/*.js',
    paths.modals + '**/*.js'
];
console.log("paths.appScripts 0");
console.log(paths.appScripts);
console.log("paths.js 0");
console.log(paths.js);
console.log();
//paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "master/js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
//paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.less = paths.components + "**/*.less";
paths.lessWatch = paths.less;
// Dests
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

console.log("paths.js");
console.log(paths.js);
console.log("paths.components");
console.log(paths.components);
console.log("paths.appScripts");
console.log(paths.appScripts);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {

    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.concatJsDest));
});
// ew
gulp.task('js:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['min:js']);
});

gulp.task('less:app', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.less)
        .pipe(less())
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.concatCssDest));
});

gulp.task('less:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.lessWatch, ['less']);
});

gulp.task('less', ['less:app']);

gulp.task('rtl', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.css)
        .pipe(rtlcss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.concatCssDest));
});

gulp.task("min:css", ["less"], function () {
    gulp.src(paths.css)
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.concatCssDest));
});

gulp.task("min", ['min:css', 'min:js']);

gulp.task("watch", ['less:watch', 'js:watch']);

gulp.task("default", ["min:js", "less"]);
```